# Jhispter create front end screen with existing Rest API or JPA entity

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Is it possible to use Jhipster to create angularJS app with existing Restful web service application. The application is powered by Spring Boot,Jpa with Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no such feature in JHipster and I doubt there'll ever be as REST web services are not standardized.

If your web services expose a swagger JSON description, you could use a swagger code generator to generate some angular code but it would be mainly the service part not the UI.

Alternatively, re-create your entities in JHipster and then modify the generated code.

If you can't change the existing app, you could use JHipster's microservices approach, recreate your entites in a JHipster microservice app and then a gateway app where your angular UI would be generated, then swap the microservice with your app and adapt UI code.

In any case, this would be a complex and tedious task and would require some good knowledge of JHipster, I would not recommend it. You'd better off writing your UI from scratch.